# Php - human_time_diff in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

So i am using a php function to echo the date of post in a custom way.

```
$last_modified = human_time_diff( get_the_date('U','','', false), current_time('timestamp') );

in my localhost offline this gives me:
11/16/2013 -> 18 days

but in the online website where I need it correct:
11/16/2013 -> 3 weeks
```

And since I am counting the days to display a custom date format, instead of days the online version counts the weeks. What may be causing the problem here? I checked both databases and they look similar like date format and such. Can it be different php versions? thank you

Comment: Do you use the same version of wordpress on local and remote machines?

Comment: ohh, I am using 3.5.1 locally and 3.7.1 online, just noticed it now. how can I in 3.7.1 change to days instead of weeks? Isnt this just related to php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is issue of different versions of wordpress. Function human_time_diff from 3.5.1 isn't same as in 3.7.1. Just look at source code in various versions:

- Wordpress v.3.5.1:
  [human_time_diff()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2101)
- Wordpress v.3.7.1:
  [human_time_diff()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2134)

For solving this issue you need to use some little knowledge of PHP. There are several methods with own cons and pros:

1. You can backport old version of function in new version
   `wp-includes/formatting.php` but with other name
   something like this `human_time_diff_351()`. But
   accordingly you need to manually change your code for using new
   function by renaming calls of old function.
2. You can replace new function by function from v.3.5.1, but it cause some side effects, 
   which you and I don't know for sure.

So I think in your situation it would probably be better use second method with testing of site after changing for checking that everything work fine. Here is code from v.3.5.1:

```
function human_time_diff( $from, $to = '' ) {
        if ( empty( $to ) )
                $to = time();
        $diff = (int) abs( $to - $from );
        if ( $diff <= HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) {
                $mins = round( $diff / MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
                if ( $mins <= 1 ) {
                        $mins = 1;
                }
                /* translators: min=minute */
                $since = sprintf( _n( '%s min', '%s mins', $mins ), $mins );
        } elseif ( ( $diff <= DAY_IN_SECONDS ) && ( $diff > HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) ) {
                $hours = round( $diff / HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
                if ( $hours <= 1 ) {
                        $hours = 1;
                }
                $since = sprintf( _n( '%s hour', '%s hours', $hours ), $hours );
        } elseif ( $diff >= DAY_IN_SECONDS ) {
                $days = round( $diff / DAY_IN_SECONDS );
                if ( $days <= 1 ) {
                        $days = 1;
                }
                $since = sprintf( _n( '%s day', '%s days', $days ), $days );
        }
        return $since;
}
```

Comment function on the lines 2134-2174 in file `wp-includes/formatting.php` v.3.7.1 and place that function instead it.

Comment: thanks, I ended up attaching that function to my theme function.php and gave it a new name. Is it ok right?